# UITextView height does not adjust properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

A beginner swift learner and stackoverflow user here. I'm practicing how to make an app and I'm observing a weird behaviour with UITextView which I cannot seem to correct...

The behaviour is to do with UITextView where if I press return to start a new line text is pushed up and when I press return again (for the second time) the text pushes down. Please find pictures below:

[UITextView after return key pressed for the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXS5V.png)

[UITextView after return key pressed for the second time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHV0n.png)

And this is my overall View Controller:

[View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzuCW.png)

The UITextView is placed inside a UIView. UIView has a height constraint (self.heightConstraint.constant) of 50 and manually increases with the size of the UITextView.contentSize.height and UITextView has height of 30 set but no constraints just pinned to top, bottom, left, right of UIView - I wanted to let the height grow a long with UIView as text view changed.

This is my code for textViewDidChange:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

        if self.heightConstraint.constant >= 50 {
            // 23 is to account for gap at top and bottom between UIView and UITextView
            self.heightConstraint.constant = self.messageTextfield.contentSize.height + 23
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

        // Scroll to bottom
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.messageArray.count - 1, section: 0)
        self.chatTableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
    }
```

This is on Xcode 10.2.1 and developing on iOS version 12.3.1

I did come across this from previous thread which seems to describe the exact same issue that I'm having but I'm not quite sure how to implement the solution supplied in the answer: [Adjusting height of UITextView to its text does not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622737/adjusting-height-of-uitextview-to-its-text-does-not-work-properly)

Could any one help me figure out what I'm missing please? Would welcome any advice to implement this in a better way as well. If I have missed any info please let me know, I'll be happy to add some more!

Comment: If [this](https://github.com/KennethTsang/GrowingTextView) is what you're trying to do, take a peek at the code, and try to use it as a guide.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I did take a look but I figured out that what actually helped was to set isScrollEnabled = false and set my heightConstraint.constant against the height of the IntrinsicContentSize rather than the height of just the content size